# What did people used to exchange for goods during the 1920s German hyperinflation while the official currency was not trusted

Tags: economy, 1920s, weimar-republic

When the 1920s  hyperinflation happened, it seemed that the rapid currency devolution is not too hard to see. This must result in the people who own and sell goods distrust the future of the currency; than they might refuse to sell their goods for the valueless currency. And this will result a hard currency such as gold or silver product. But those hard currencies are too valuable and most of the people don't have it for exchange. So, what kind of thing (hard currencies) would most of the people trust and used for exchange(trade)?

By the way, how did those famous Germany companies exist during this disaster? The breaking of capital chain because of the currency devolution would cause horrible situation for an enterprise.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Wheelbarrows of cash and barter are the standard answer.  Also note the denominations depicted in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_the_Weimar_Republic#Hyperinflation).

Comment: Also: [Goldmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_gold_mark) coins were still a thing, even as circulation throzgh banks was almost nonexistant.

Comment: @Trish Gold coins were already scarce in 1914 and for practical purposes non existent in the 1920-1924 timeframe.

Comment: Hard currency for the average person was not available. The average tourist that could exchange in the Black market were so few that it had no impact. It was a totally different situation than that after WWII, where a certain amount of 'tradable goods' were available through the occupation forces. Companies that produced export goods had it easier since the foreign currency earned was needed for reparations payments. Their suppliers also benefited from this situation, since without their goods the exports goods counld not be made.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, the problem with a wheelbarrow full of cash is that you might get mugged for your wheelbarrow.

Comment: @markcwallace Wheelbarrows were not really needed apart from 1923.  The banks kept printing larger and larger face-value banknotes until the velocity of inflation outstripped it.

Comment: The one line answer to this is 'cigarettes'.

Comment: @quarague More than 1 line is needed to explain where the tobacco came from (**not** from occupation forces as after 1945). Tobacco, at the time, was maily imported from Greece, Turkey and Bulgaria.

Comment: @Mark Getting mugged for a wheelbarrow full of cash is relatively unlikely if the wheelbarrow is worth more than the cash inside.

Answer (score 4):

The subject is covered in the book “Dying of Money”, by Jens O. Parssons.

Inflation started taking off in Germany in 1922. By the end of the inflation, near the end of 1923, prices were at least quadrupling every week. ‘Fair’ interest rates rose to 22% per day. For those who could afford restaurants, the price of the meal could increase by 20% between ordering and getting the bill. Printers did their best to keep up with the demand for money, and of course the face values of the notes increased dramatically, but even so money was always short.

People took to carrying money in bales, and were desperate to spend it before its value dropped. However, people with goods, particularly farmers, were reluctant to take soon-to-be-worthless money for their perfectly good food. Barter became prevalent, but not everyone had something useful to barter. The middle classes were almost wiped out, they pawned their possessions to survive, and looked for jobs in field or factory where real goods were produced. Malnutrition and even starvation were rife. Where possible businesses used foreign currencies for their dealings, but many closed leading to mass unemployment.

The problem was fixed by the introduction of the Rentenmark. The idea that was sold to the public was that only a fixed number of Rentenmarks would be printed, so they could not lose value. The rate was fixed in November 1923 as 1 trillion old Reichsmarks to 1 Rentenmark. It worked. The Rentenmark held its value.

There were winners and losers. A big winner was the German government. All their debts, denominated in Reichsmarks, were effectively wiped out. Others also benefited. The total prewar mortgage debt of Germany, totalling 40 billion marks, was worth less than 1 American cent by the end of the inflation. Effectively, everyone who owed money had those debts wiped out. Conversely, anyone who had monetised savings lost them all. This included pensioners, many of whom were forced back to work. Bonds became worthless, which affected many trustees who by law had to invest in bonds.

German hyperinflation was not the last or even the worst. That in Hungary in 1946 holds the record, with a monthly price increase of 4.19 * 10 to the power 16 in July of that year. These days, a common response in our globalised world is to resort to using foreign currency. At least then, some money circulates reliably. In Zimbabwe in 2009, the Zimbabwe dollar was actually completely taken out of circulation in favour of the American dollar.

The book “Hyperinflation: A World History” by He Liping is a good general reference.

Comment: The name of the currency before the introduction of the **Rentenmark** (1923) and **Reichsmark** (1924) was called **Mark** (1871).